# how do I bevel the control point of a curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

This is a really simple issue but I can't find a way to do what I need, nor a hint on the web. I have a simple 2D curve with vector type handles. The control points form 90 degrees edges. I'm looking for a way to bevel some edges, to round them up. On the attached image: white is the control point I have, green is what I need (right now I need the rounded edge)

[image: control point needs to be beveled]

Comment: It could be possible to subdivide the curve on that region, and tweak handles' length of the newly created control points (so the original curve vertice should be moved / deleted).

Comment: That could be done but I hoped there would be a simple way. Especially because this isn't a special case, I need this rounding up of control points again and again when modelling.

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be a little uncomfortable; you could use scaling of the control point to desired location; you can find details in the answer I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess curves can't be beveled like you want...

One (dirty) way is:

- in object mode, convert the curve to mesh (<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>)
- in edit mode (of the new mesh), select the vertices, bevel with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>
- in object mode, convert back the mesh into curve

Comment: If there is no such function in curve editing, then I guess I agree that converting to mesh and then back to curve is the best way to work around.

Answer (score 6):

You could scale curve point to its hadles' plane.

First, for better results make the type of handles of the control points to *Free* (with all curve points selected press <kbd>V</kbd> > *Free*).

1. Select the handles of the curve vertice in the corner (where you'd like to make 'bevel'). Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select both them.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to snap the cursor to selection.
3. Select the curve vertice itself, and deselect the handles (click on them with <kbd>MMB</kbd>).
4. Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale the control point to the cursor location:

[image]

Note that it's also possible to change the location of the handles in order to tweak the cursor location.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, I'm going to try this. But will the resulting rounding up be a perfect quarter of a circle?

Comment: It will be perfect quarter of the circle only if those hadles' legnth is equal, which *roughly* is after the curve is added. You still can scale up or down the handles *and* preserving them being equal by selecting them and then the curve point itself, pressing `Alt`+`.` (dot) to set the Pivot Point to Active and scaling. Other then that I think you should only measure the angle between edge formed by the handles and the point itself, which afaik isn't possible by default.

Answer (score 5):

There's an addon that ships with Blender called "Curve Tools". If you enable that addon, on your "N" panel, while in Edit Mode, you will find a tab called "Curve Edit", which provides you with several "extra" features while working with curves, including Fillet/Chamfer, which should do what you need.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is to late but others may had same question too.

I am working on [BsMax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M926K8FvHtQ) add-on that simulate 3Ds Max UI inside the blender. With this add-on you have primitive objects and curve editing tools like 3Ds Max.

BsMax is free and opensource you can find last update download link [here](http://nevilart.blogspot.com/2019/02/bsmax.html).

[image: BsMax in action]