# How to round sharp edges on curve?

Tags: modeling

I converted a mesh to a curve, to create a path in 3D space, and now I want to round the sharp edges. (Please see the top-right quadrant in the image below).  What's the best way to round the sharp edges? Tks!

[image]

Comment: Part of problem was the curve was a poly, so I converted it to Bezier and now I can round the corners by adjusting the handles. But I'm having trouble controlling the direction in which I move the handles. I want to constrain the handle rotation to an axis/plane. How do I do that?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of this, actually: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41696/how-do-i-bevel-the-control-point-of-a-curve?rq=1

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better/66367#66367

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this sort of problem before, and while it doesn't work in all cases, one of the easiest / fastest methods I've found is this:

- Convert the curve to a mesh.
- Vertex bevel the corners - this gives you a nice control over the number of segments and width of the bevel
- Convert back into a curve.

Your eventual curve will have a lot more control points near the corners (typically one per vertex after the bevel) and be a little more difficult to handle via the curve controls as a result, so I'd do this step last.  It's also reasonably destructive, but it works.

Comment: OK, many thanks. I was afraid of that. For what it's worth, it turns out I am now able to control the rotation of the handles -- by double-clicking the portion of the handle in question. Once I double-clicked, then I could rotate the handle normally, with direction constraints.

Comment: There are more non-destructive methods, there are curve only methods, and I'm sure there are better methods - but when you really just want a round corner, this one is quick.